# How to get current location without clicking the button in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
//*some code
 const [lat, setLat] = useState(null);
 const [lng, setLng] = useState(null);
 const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);

 const getLocation = () => {
      if (!navigator.geolocation) {
           setStatus('Geolocation is not supported by your browser');
      } else {
           setStatus('Locating...');
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                setStatus(null);
                setLat(position.coords.latitude);
                setLng(position.coords.longitude);
           }, () => {
                setStatus('Unable to retrieve your location');
           });
      }
 }
 const point = {
      lat: lat,
      lng: lng
 };
 const dest = {
      lat: 123,
      lng: 456
 };
//*some code
```

I got the reference from here https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-use-the-geolocation-api-in-your-react-app-54e87c9c6c94

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this one. Previously findNearestLocation function was called before set latitude and longitude. At that moment mylocation was null. That was the reason.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import findNearestLocation from 'map-nearest-location';

export default function App() {
 const [myLocation, setMylocation] = useState(null);
 const [nearestLocation, setNearestLocation] = useState(null);
 const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);

 const locations = [
     {
       lat: 40.7722691,
       lng: -74.3008176
     },
     {
       lat: 40.682638,
       lng: -73.941015
     },
     {
       lat: 40.870347,
       lng: -74.105810
     },
     {
       lat: 40.7374197,
       lng: -74.2719785
     }
   ];

 useEffect(() => {
      getLocation();
 }, []);

 useEffect(() => {
     if(myLocation) {
          const nearest = findNearestLocation(myLocation, locations);
          setNearestLocation(nearest);
     }
 },[myLocation]);

 const getLocation = () => {
      if (!navigator.geolocation) {
           setStatus('Geolocation is not supported by your browser');
      } else {
           setStatus('Locating...');
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                setStatus(null);
                setMylocation({
                     lat: position.coords.latitude,
                     lng: position.coords.longitude
                })
           }, () => {
                setStatus('Unable to retrieve your location');
           });
      }
 }

 console.log(nearestLocation);

 return (
      <div className="App">
           <h1>map here</h1>
      </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. But please, make your answer more clear and explain the context of it. Don't put some code here without any explanation or any background info. Please follow the [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Add useEffect hook and call getLocation function inside it.

```
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(null);
  const [lng, setLng] = useState(null);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getLocation();
  },[]);

  const getLocation = () => {
       if (!navigator.geolocation) {
            setStatus('Geolocation is not supported by your browser');
       } else {
            setStatus('Locating...');
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                 setStatus(null);
                 setLat(position.coords.latitude);
                 setLng(position.coords.longitude);
            }, () => {
                 setStatus('Unable to retrieve your location');
            });
       }
  }
```

Comment: it doesn't work, I get the same error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toRad')

Comment: i use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/map-nearest-location/v/1.1.2

Comment: Can you post the complete code?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-leaf-oh64df?file=/src/App.js